# NSFetchedResultsController consistent delay in updating UITableView cell; insert works instantaneously

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a `UITableView` (with custom cells, if that matters) hooked up to an `NSFetchedResultsController`. My app also uses push notifications. When a remote notification arrives, I update my (core)data model in two phases:

1) Get title (with some custom data) and store it as a new core data `Entity`. Here I call `NSManagedObjectContext save()`. `NSFetchedResultsController` picks up the insert and fires it's delegate method `didChangeObject` with `NSFetchedResultsChangeType`=`NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert`. The tableview is instantly updated. (A new row is inserted)

2) Download more content related to the cell via `NSURLSession` insert it into the above `Entity` and again call the `save() method`. `NSFetchedResultsController` again picks up the update and fires it's delegate method `didChangeObject` with `NSFetchedResultsChangeType`=`NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate`. This is where I call my `configureCell` method. The tableView is updated but with a consistent delay of about 10 seconds.

At both stages (download-context save-update tableview) the data that needs to be shown *has* already been persisted by core data. (For e.g. inside my `configureCell..` method, I know I'm not setting any cell label to `nil` or suchlike.

My `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate methods:

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
[self.mainTableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
[self.mainTableView endUpdates];
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
UITableView *tableView = self.mainTableView;

switch(type) {

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
        [self configureCell:(MessageTableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}
```

Other things that I've tried inside `case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:`

1. Tried calling `processPendingChanges` before context `save`
2. Called `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` instead of calling `configureCell` directly
3. Tried wrapping the update.. methods inside `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`(even though I already have one pair which should do the job)
4. `[tableView reloadData]`
5. `numberOfRowsInSection` is not 0!
6. The `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate methods run on the main thread only.

In a nutshell, all (?) the proper delegate methods are being called correctly. Yet I see a consistent ~10 sec delay when updating a cell. However, insertion happens almost instantaneously. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't show the code where you update the table after the network operation completes but I would guess that you aren't dispatching the update on the main queue.

Comment: Well, if by "dispatching" the update, you mean calling `save`, then no, I'm calling `save` from the `NSURLSession` delegate method `URLSession:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingToURL:` which is NOT on the main thread if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: So you're using a background thread context you created and saving the change up?

Comment: No, I'm not using any parent/child contexts. There's simply one context object inside my AppDelegate declared as `atomic` which the `NSURLSession` threads are using.

Comment: No, I mean are you wrapping any actions that update the UI (such as reload on the tableview) in a `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue,^{ UIUpdate code here });`

Comment: @Paulw11 NSFRC works when updates are NOT on the main queue. The update happens when the main context is merged with a child context. Iirc

Comment: @Paulw11 I don't update the tableview directly from any non-main thread. All tableview updating is done via the `NSFetchedResultsController` delegates that I've implemented. Not having to update the tableview from other threads was one main reason for using the NSFRC in the first place

Comment: Can you clarify when the delay occurs: after saving context, before controllerWillChangeContent, or after controllerDidChangeObjectAtIndexPath, before configureCell, etc

Comment: @Paulw11 I just called context `save` on the main queue (via `dispatch_get_main_queue..`, and updates are now propagated instantly! The `NSFRC`'s delegate methods always run on the main thread. However the delay seems to be occuring because I'm performing a `save` in a background thread? I still find the behavior strange though - my background `save` actually did save data & inform the `NSFRC` too. It just introduces a tableview refresh delay somehow. Any thoughts?

Comment: @pbasdf See above comment. `save` occurs (on a background thread), and all 3 methods of the `NSFRC` are called on time. Even `configureCell` does its work(of setting cell contents). The tableview simply sits there for some time before updating.

Comment: A very common cause of UI delays is code executing on a background thread.  My guess is that the save to the NSFRC on a background thread results in the delegate methods being called on the background thread - if you don't then explicitly dispatch the code in the delegate methods on the main queue it will be performed on the background queue too.

Comment: @Paulw11 Oh! Delegate methods being called on background threads! Whew! However `[NSThread currentThread]` says that the delegate methods are being called on the main thread! Is there something in between `save` and the delegates being called thats causing the delay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Paulw11 's comment about `dispatch_async...` set me off in the right direction. The problem lies in the fact that I have been using the same `ManagedObjectContext` object in two different threads even though they do not simultaneously access it at the same time. As soon as I dispatched my `save` calls (which were on a background thread) on the main queue (by wrapping it inside `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue,^{ UIUpdate code here });`), the delays disappeared. A possible explanation would be that calling `save` on a background thread results in the delegate methods being called on the background thread.

Anyway, back to the solution - never share the same `ManagedObjectContext` object between multiple threads. [Use parent/child context relationships](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/) if you're updating core date in more than one thread. `NSFetchedResultsController` also plays nicely with this pattern.